# Take screenshot of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, phantomjs

Hey i am trying to render a screenshot of a specific element with phantomjs. I am using the phantomjs bridge for nodejs: phantom

This what i got so far:

```
page.includeJs('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js');
var elementBounds = page.evaluate(function () {
    var clipRect = document.querySelector("#yw0").getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        top: clipRect.top,
        left: clipRect.left,
        width: clipRect.width,
        height: clipRect.height
    };
});
var oldClipRect = page.clipRect;
page.clipRect = elementBounds;
page.render('element.png');
page.clipRect = oldClipRect;
```

It is somehow not working i always get a screenshot of the whole page! What did i wrong?

Comment: There is an easier way out without using phantomjs , interested?

Comment: @MohitBhasi I need to use phantomjs because my code is part of a bigger programm

Comment: @MohitBhasi Maybe you can post this way as answer. So i could try to implement it somehow in phantom.

Comment: It just uses html's canvas and draws the image

Comment: @MohitBhasi so i could convert it in a dataUrl and when it's returned i can write the file with nodejs

Comment: Ok check my answer out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using NightmareJs. That's my code:

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var Screenshot = require('nightmare-screenshot');
var nightmare = new Nightmare();
nightmare.goto('url');
nightmare.use(Screenshot.screenshotSelector('element.png', 'img[id="yw0"]'));
nightmare.run();
```